# Spring Boot: ComponentScan vs Declared Bean in an Autoconfigured Jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, component-scan

Suppose I have a jar with a Spring Component called `MyComponent`.  This jar is a Spring Boot "autoconfigured" jar, meaning that it has a Configuration class (annotated with `@Configuration`), and additionally, a `META-INF/spring.factories` file on the classpath.  This jar is not an executable jar by itself; it is a library that is meant for inclusion in a Spring Boot application.

These files look as follows:

`MyComponent.java`, in package `com.mine.components`:

```
@Component
public class MyComponent {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyComponent.class);

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        logger.info("MyComponent inited");
    }
}
```

`MyConfiguration.java`, in package `com.mine.config`:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mine.components")
public class MyConfiguration {
}
```

`spring.factories`, in `META-INF` under `src/main/resources`:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=com.mine.config.MyConfiguration
```

If I include this jar in a Spring Boot project with the above three files, the `MyComponent` component is NOT detected (the log message never prints).

But if I instead remove the `@ComponentScan` and declare `MyComponent` using the `@Bean` annotation as follows, it is detected:

```
@Bean
public MyComponent myComponent() {
    return new MyComponent();
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Difference beetween ComponentScan and declared Bean inside @Configuration class:

@ComponentScan: You enable auto-scanning (default using current folder path), optionally you can specify an basePackage where spring will found yours beans.

@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mine.components")
You're saying to Spring that in this package("com.mine.components"), you'll define yours beans typically using annotations (@Component, @Entity, @Controller, @Service, @Repository or more).

@Bean: This way you define your beans manually inside @Configuration class, but Spring has to discover your configuration class, usually using @ComponentScan, @SpringBootApplication.

META-INF/spring.factories: you define an custom autoconfiguration